# Tkinter - как сделать независимые от регистра клавиши?

Tags: python, tkinter

Изучаю Tkinter, пишу пробные приложения
Понадобилось сделать смену текста по нажатию O на клавиатуре
Сделал через:
`ch.bind("<o>", eeee)`, но возникла проблема: 
Если я нажимаю o с выключенным Caps-Lock, событие срабатывает, но если Caps-Lock включен - событие не работает. Как можно решить данную проблему?
Полный код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()

ch = Label(text="j")
ch.place(x=50, y=51)

def eeee(e):
  ch.config(text="e")

ch.bind("<o>", eeee)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Только добавлением второго бинда на заглавную букву `ch.bind("<O>", eeee)`. По-другому никак.

Answer (score 0):

Можно привязываться к события `<Key>` (или к событиям нажатия/отпускания кнопок - `<KeyPress>`, `<KeyRelease>` соответственно) и смотреть поле `keycode` события - для любой клавиши там будет одинаковый код независимо от регистра или раскладки клавиатуры. Пример:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()


def on_key(event):
    print(event.keycode, event.keysym)


root.bind("<Key>", on_key)

root.mainloop()
```

Пример вывода (тут я жму латинскую <kbd>a</kbd>, потом ее же с зажатым <kbd>shift</kbd>, с зажатым <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, со включенным <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, переключаюсь в русскую раскладку - код `keycode` для этой клавиши все равно остается 38):

```
38 a
50 Shift_L
38 A
37 Control_L
38 a
66 Caps_Lock
38 A
64 Alt_L
50 ISO_Next_Group
38 Cyrillic_EF
50 Shift_L
38 Cyrillic_ef
66 Caps_Lock
38 Cyrillic_ef
```

Проверил на Windows - работает аналогично, но `keycode` выводит 65.